# Python3 numpy error : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to use SVM classifier on MFCC features for natural and spoofed speech.

```
import scipy.io as scio
import sklearn as sk
import numpy as np

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing

#Load feature for training
print("Training features for Natural Speech")
mat_nat = scio.loadmat('/home/speechlab/Documents/feature_cqcc/nat_featdd_train.mat')
mat_nat_ar =  mat_nat['genuineFeatureCell']
print (mat_nat_ar.shape) #(1507,1)

print("Training features for Spoofed Speech")
mat_sp = scio.loadmat('/home/speechlab/Documents/feature_cqcc/spf_featdd_train.mat')
mat_sp_ar =  mat_sp['spoofFeatureCell']
print (mat_sp_ar.shape) #(1507,1)

#Concatenating  natural and spoofed feature array
print ("Concatenating 2 arrays \n Natural feature array followed by Spoofed Feature")
feat_con =  np.concatenate((mat_nat_ar, mat_sp_ar),axis=0)
print (feat_con.shape) # (3014,1)

scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_train = np.array([[mat_nat_ar],[mat_sp_ar]])
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
print (X_train)
print (type(X_train))
y_train = np.array([[0,1]])
print (type(y_train))
clf = svm.LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I am getting this error

```
File "feature_cqcc.py", line 27, in <module>
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 462, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 625, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 649, in partial_fit
    force_all_finite='allow-nan')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 527, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have tried to convert X_train and y_train into list, but got same error. I know that the error is caused due to mismatch of data. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Check the type: `X_train = np.array([[mat_nat_ar],[mat_sp_ar]])`

Comment: Type of X_train is  `numpy.ndarray`. Why isn't `scaler.fit_transform`  working?

Comment: And the dtype and shape? numpy arrays of floats work with the scaler, you have a wrong type or shape somewhere.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing: `np.array([[mat_nat_ar],[mat_sp_ar]])`? Do you want to stack the two arrays as columns together, so that the resultant shape is `(1507,2)`?

Comment: Also are you sure you want to append a feature after another feature as you are doing currently in your `np.concatenate`? This will be treated as a single feature in sklearn.

Comment: @VivekKumar I want both concatenate mat_nat_ar and mat_sp_ar to form single array so that shape of resultant array  is (3014,1)

Comment: And why is that? Are both these arrays part of a single feature or two different features?

Comment: Both are different features and I am also providing 2 different class (0 for natural feature and 1 for spoofed feature) Are there any other alternative, kindly let me to know how to concatenate these fatures?

Comment: Two features need to be in different columns. `np.concatenate((mat_nat_ar, mat_sp_ar),axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

`StandardScaler()` takes 2 dimensional array only.

From [documentation:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit)

> Parameters:    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape [n_samples,
>   n_features] The data used to compute the mean and standard deviation
>   used for later scaling along the features axis.
>
> y Ignored

Hence you have write new custom normalization for a `ndarray()`.